# Launch a URL from a WinForms app

Tags: winforms

I've got a VB.NET WinForms app in which I have the need to refer the user to a web page with documentation/help. I realize the LinkButton would get the trick done, but what I want is a standard Button control to launch the system default browser when that button is clicked. The only code I can find references the Win32 API, hooking the ShellExecute command:

```
ShellExecute(Me.Handle.ToInt32, "Open", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/", CStr(0), CStr(0), WindowStyle.SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Does anyone else know how to do this in a "proper and pure" .NET manner?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
```

should work

Comment: Is there a way to check if the link has been launched or not?

Comment: @Ali123 Using this method, No. And I don't know of another reliable method to achieve that.

Comment: Hi FallenAvatar, thanks for your answer. I found out how to check if the process started. check the first comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196207/confirm-that-the-url-was-launched-successfully-in-c-sharp#comment104708278_59196207

Comment: I get an exception `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '`

Comment: This solves my `Win32Exception` problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62534375/44547

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (url); not working in .Net Core 3.1