# Link in winforms application which redirect to http page in default browser

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is it possible to add to the winformac application link control something which, when clicked, redirects you to the default browser with page opened for example google.com?

Answer (score 2):

[Launch a URL from a WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425381/launch-a-url-from-a-winforms-app)