# Take saved URL and open web broswer c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a saved url in a database linked to a windows form. How do I take the url and open a web broswer?

this is where its stored

```
m_dtMedia.Rows[m_rowPosition]["File_Path"]
```

what I want is when you click a button for the web broswer to oepn up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch a URL from a WinForms app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425381/launch-a-url-from-a-winforms-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start a new process with the url as the target/filename:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

This will have the effect of using the default browser to load the url.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I mixed it with the other answer and used System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com")

Comment: This will block your UI until the browser opens.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void OpenBrowser(string url)
{
        if (url != null)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process.Start();
        }
}
```

Since spawning another process takes a bit of time, while that is occuring your UI will be blocked.  I recommend calling this method from a background thread.  For example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{OpenBrowser(url);});
```

This method is used because calling Process.Start(string) from a UI thread causes an exception

Comment: This is waaaay too much code for what the question asks. :) Not downvoting, but `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com")` works fine by itself.

Comment: Never seen anyone use url.dll,FileProtocolHandler before.  Interesting decision.  Why this method?

Comment: Calling Process.Start from the UI thread will block your UI making it unresponsive until the browser opens the site.  You cannot call Process.Start(string) from the UI thread--it causes an exception.  To open a process from a thread other than the main UI thread you have to go through the above hoops.

Comment: _"You cannot call Process.Start(string) from the UI thread--it causes an exception."_ - no it doesn't. To verify, I have just tried it and it works without an exception. It will however block the UI as you say, but (on my machine at least) launching a url is so quick it is not noticeable.

Comment: It used to throw a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception; maybe that got fixed in the Framework at some point.