# Confirm that the URL was Launched successfully in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, url, uwp

I am developing a solution in Winforms and Console windows.
when i call the following line, the browser opens successfully:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

but how can i confirm that it opened successfully?

I was using this line in UWP which returns the status of the opening but it doesn't work in the background

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

Is there a way to confirm that the link has launched as the one in UWP?

Comment: `var process = Process.Start([string])`: this method returns a Process object. Or null, if nothing was started or the process exited right after. See also the [WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforinputidle) method and the [Process.MainWindowTitle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle) property.

Comment: Call `WaitForExit` and check `ExitCode`

Comment: **"I was using this line in UWP but it doesn't work in the background"** about this issue, the Remarks from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) mentions this API must be called from within an ASTA thread (also known as the UI thread) in UWP. So it won't work in the background.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for your response. It is clearly stating that in the documentation so i should have read better before jumping to questions.
// Returns:
        //     A new System.Diagnostics.Process that is associated with the process resource,
        //     or null if no process resource is started

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, i checked the documentation after i was facing a strange issue where when i am calling the LaunchUriAsync from a toast notification onBackgroundActivation, it was not opening the website. I guess that is why they have a "protocol" activation that can open a website directly from the toast. But, sometimes i want to handle the logic of opening a website on my side before opening it. thanks for the support

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski can you please elaborate on the difference between "Wait for Exit" and "Wait for Idle"? It looks like wait for exit will also work on processes without a UI which is a plus but i am opening the web browser for now.

Comment: If you want to activate toast from the background and then handle your logic before opening a website, it is not feasible to achieve it.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, i have already achieved it. I am sending the command to launch the URL to the Winforms app which is always running in the system tray.