# Call default browser with URL and set a target

Tags: c#, browser, default, target

I don't know if there is a mechanism to do this: normally one would simply call process start with a URL as the string parameter - has anyone any knowlege or sugestions as to how to add a target?

Google has been singularly unhelpful or else my queries have been a tad useless.

As in the behavior you get with :

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank">link in a new window</a>
```

Comment: did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024/open-a-url-from-windows-forms

Comment: gordatron - that does not address the target issue; it is simply calling process start with a URL

Comment: am I missing something? when i read this I don't know what the difference between URL and target is (sorry if i am being thick).

Comment: Arif - a target as in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: ahhh so you want to force the link to open in a new window.

Comment: can you host a webpage that re-directs the user? so all links would be to your web app which re-directs them to the requested page in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

What is the harm in launching the default browser ?

you may do this but what if firefox is not available ! !

```
ProcessStartInfo proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo("firefox.exe");
proc1.Arguments = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp";
                  //"http://stackoverflow.com";
Process.Start(proc1);
```

Comment: var call3 = @"http://www.Whatever";                                Process.Start(call3); Will call the default browser without a need to specify a particular browser - but it will not set a target!  Simon

Comment: What do you mean by target ? I added your so called target now what is the behaviour you are expecting ?

Comment: I'm obviously not making myself clear here.  If you go to the website referenced you can see the parameters for "target=".  One of them is _self; which is defined as: _self

Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default).  Now if I open a web page using the Process.Start function and then open anther web page using the Process.Start again these web pages will open in two tabs of the same browser (in i.e.).  I want the second page to replace the first page so there is only one tab open - I had identified target=_self as a way of doing that - but any other is OK