# Open default browser from listView Subitem click

Tags: c#, listview

Trying to figure out how to open the default browser from a click on a listView subitem.

Im creating my listView like this:

```
                string[] row1 = { username, "Start", proxy, "0", "0" };

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

                item.Text = numeret.ToString();
                item.Tag = numeret;
                listView1.Items.Add(item).SubItems.AddRange(row1);
```

Basically i want the user to be able to click username which then should open the default web browser and take the user to a certain url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer: [Open a URL from Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024/open-a-url-from-windows-forms)

```
ProcessStartInfo sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://mysite.com/");  
Process.Start(sInfo);
```