# Opening a URL in the default browser in a Windows 8 desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` from a desktop application to start the default browser to visit a link, as below.  This is using C# with .NET 4.0 on Windows 8 Pro RTM.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"http://www.google.com",
    UseShellExecute = true
});
```

This works fine under Windows 7, but under Windows 8 I am getting an exception that can be reproduced in LINQPad.  The exceptions are:

`UseShellExecute = true` gives Win32Exception: Class not registered.
`UseShellExecute = false` gives Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

How can open a URL in the default browser?

Answer (score 21):

For **WinRT apps only**, it's simply

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you need to specify the process name under Win8.  The answer below comes from [Armin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121028/armin) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12248929/2608).

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", @"http://www.google.com");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```