# How to open links in wpf webview in default explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, webview

My webview display a html page which contains lots of links, if I click the link, the new page will open in the webview, is there a way to open the link in default browser rather than in webview?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [`WebView.NavigationStarting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) event as follows:

```
private void navigationStartingHandler(object sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501174/opening-a-url-in-the-default-browser-in-a-windows-8-desktop-application) are more answers about opening web pages in default browser

Comment: Hi, my project is wpf, not windows8 app, there's no such an event in wpf webview

Comment: @James, could you provide link to the `WebView` class you're referring to? Because I can not find other `WebView` that is part of .NET Framework, which is not the one referred in my answer. Are you, perhaps, referring to [Awesomium WebView](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_WebView.htm)?