# Shell() website url

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to run website url using `Shell()` command? I saw someone post

> Shell() can only read the executable path

But regarding to this site http://www.vb6.us/forums/general-questions/attaching-website-links-your-command-button `Shell()` can used to run the website url.

I have some website url inside my XML file and I tried to run them using `Shell()` command as my XML file also containing .exe file path. So I am running those .exe file and website url like this

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 0 To 9
    For j = 0 To 9
        If MenuListBox.SelectedItem = MenuListBox(i, j, 0) Then

            Shell(MenuListBox(i, j, 1))

        End If
    Next
Next
```

I am using array to store each of elements inside my XML file.

So the problem here is, I can only run my `.exe` files and when running website url it said that

> File not found

Even though my path is correct. I did used the `Process.Start()` also but it only working for the website url, not the .exe file. It returns me this error.

> The system cannot find the file specified

Kindly to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its a Windows.Forms App, process.start with a FULL URL, may open the default browser (Ex: process.start("http://stackoverflow.com")

Comment: Yes it can open my website url if using `Process.Start()` BUT it cannot run my `.exe` file

Comment: Ah! do you mean that URLs are OK but the issue it's with EXE. Ok, its a WinForms app? Why don't you check the path before (io.file.exists)? Are any parameters needed? Are permissions granted? Did you check  the returned values of Shell or Process,Start?

Comment: I am using Windows Form App. I already check all my `.exe` path and my website url. All are correct.

Comment: Check with notepad.exe. If works, something in your exe may be

Comment: I'm not sure either it needs any parameter but IF I use `Shell()` function all my `.exe` files can run BUT not working for website url :(

Comment: It's working if I use `notepad.exe`. Too bad. I cannot figure out why because my `.exe` files are all doing fine. Nothing wrong with the path also. All are correct.

Comment: can you post your exe file path as you pass it to shell method?

Comment: Hi @fofik , my exe file path is inside the XML file and I store it using array so when I shell() it I do like this `Shell(MenuListBox(i, j, 1))`. But since `Process.Start()` is the suitable method to run both .exe and website url so I used it instead of `Shell()`. My program is completed already with the `Process.Start()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@Capitán Cavernícola` for your suggestion.

```
If path.toupper like "*.EXE"  
  shell path
Else 
  process.start (path)
End if
```

I took your code and change the `path.toupper like "*.EXE"` to `Path.Contains(".exe") Then`

Here is my coding that working all fine now.

```
Dim Path As String = MenuListBox(i, j, 1)

                    If Path.Contains(".exe") Then
                        Shell(Path)
                    Else
                        Process.Start(Path)
                    End If
```

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Process.Start() can be used for url and executables and other files. If you pass a path to a file, like a doc file, it is open with default application. In your case if you pass a url like "http://www.google.com" it will be opened with your default browser.

[According to MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing
>   the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu.
>   Therefore, the file name does not need to represent an executable
>   file. It can be of any file type for which the extension has been
>   associated with an application installed on the system. For example
>   the file name can have a .txt extension if you have associated text
>   files with an editor, such as Notepad, or it can have a .doc if you
>   have associated.doc files with a word processing tool, such as
>   Microsoft Word. Similarly, in the same way that the Run dialog box can
>   accept an executable file name with or without the .exe extension, the
>   .exe extension is optional in the fileName parameter. For example, you
>   can set the fileName parameter to either "Notepad.exe" or "Notepad".

opening a url [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024/open-a-url-from-windows-forms) and [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/using_processstart_to_link_to.html)

Comment: He's talking only about EXE, seems to be

Comment: I am getting Win32Exception was unhandled error when running `.exe` using `Process.Start()`

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, to get time to check the real solution:

```
If path.toupper like "*.EXE"  
  shell path
Else 
  process.start (path)
End if
```

But if you have a Win32Exception (show us the full message) ... they used to appear on 32/64 bits issue. etc. But, as Shell is working, I think you have a Credentials issue= permissions of that folder/exe.

Place that exe on another granted location to test.

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified` 

 Here is the error that appear if I use `Process.Start()` to run `.exe` file

Comment: If the file is there and you can open it outside the app > permissions.
As I say, place it in a granted location, an tell me the result. Or try to run your app as an Administrator, etc.