# POST data from Desktop application to MVC and show view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webrequest

I have a desktop application that I take date and POST it to my web server. Then I would like the browser to open on the client and show the view with the posted data filled out on the form. Currently it posts and the data is transferred successfully, but the browser never opens and show the page on the client.
Is it possible to do this?
Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you add more info? I guess you are using `HttpClient` or something similar and what to do similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024/open-a-url-from-windows-forms.  In that case you need to change request to GET as there is not way to open a browser process and send POST request to it. Or you can use `WebBrowser` control inside your desktop app. It depends what you are trying to reach.

Comment: You need to open browser for showing data?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windoows forms? You could use WebBrowserControl to show web content on your client

Comment: @klashar - there is not way to open a browser process and send POST request to it. That answered my question. Many thanks!